# jQuery detect value of input

Tags: javascript, jquery, input

I have got this script for detect value of input. It works well if I write down something to input, but why this thing for works if input have prefiled data?

```
if ($("input").val().length != 0) {
    $(this).siblings().css ({
        top: "20px",
        left: "0",
        fontSize: ".7em",
        color: "#8B8B8B"
    });    
};
```

Here is my codepen http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qZZBXr?editors=1010

Comment: Could you post the complete code? Your pen does nothing.

Comment: Your questions seems a bit unclear. At least to me. Please correct your question by adding more details on what you want to do and what is not working.

Comment: Your `this` isn't referring to what you think, making all your question unclear. Now to answer you question, you need to check for `defaultValue` compare to current one. And this should obviously done following some user interaction like e.g using change event

Comment: The check only occurs if something changes, you could trigger the change on load therefore it validates the pre-defined input.

Comment: It's not clear what you want to do. Are you just trying to run this code when the page loads, or whenever something is typed in to the element? If the latter, does the styling need to be removed if the value is emptied? Some detail would help a lot.

Answer (score 0):

As you have multiple inputs on the page, for each you will have to check the value. Following code should work for you

```
$(function() {

  $("input").each(function(input) {
    if ($(this).val().length != 0)
    {
      $(this).siblings().css({
        top: "20px",
        left: "0",
        fontSize: ".7em",
        color: "#8B8B8B"
      });
    };
  })

})
```

Here is [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mtechdev/gq2LdLwf/) code.

Please note this will only work at page load. If you want to change color of labels when input values are changed then you will have to use input change handler for it.